# Spinner in the bottom bar

Tags: android, layout, android-spinner

I am trying to design the bottom bar where it contains 5 items which has 3 text view and 2 spinner in the bottom bar. However, I am not able to adjust same design - please check out the images.

First image is how I want to get it and second image is how I am getting. Another problem is I am getting space at the right side of the filter in some devices.

Here is my layout design

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkindate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/calender"
        android:text="CHECK IN DATE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#30000000" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/checkintime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/timer"
        android:text="CHECK IN TIME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#30000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hrs"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/clock" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/hrspinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#30000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rooms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/roomshr" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/roomspinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#30000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/filter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/filterr"
        android:text="FILTER"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: I want design like this]

[image: this how i am getting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bad design. Bottom navigation should be for screen changing.
Here some library
https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation

Here design documentation from google
https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#

In my opinion filter is better to put on ToolBar or ActionBar.

---

Edited:

If you want achieve the same design, first of all you need make text smaller. Second spinner item shouldn't be real spinner. Just make text with triangle icon. When you press on it show custom view with items above you bottom toolbar

Comment: means like tabs fragments but i am making hotel APP just like OYO and roomstonite Bottom bar

Comment: Added some comments

Comment: and i also have the spinner in the bottom bar

Comment: how can i achieve the position sir of the custom view